# C++: factory design, can't push_back on vector

Tags: c++

I am currently designing a video game in c++ for a school project. We were advised to use an abstractfactory desing to create our objects.

When playing the game I'd like to store the objects (player, enemy, weapons etc.) in one vector of entitie (superclass) pointers.
I define my levels in a class GameLogic, but when I try to fill the vector with derived classes, I sometimes get error, sometimes I don't.
In this example, I add some enemies, speedpowerups and healthpowerup. SpeedPowerUp and HealthPowerUp are the same, only difference is the name.
But adding a HealthPowerUp works, adding a SpeedPowerUp doesn't work...

These are some snippets from my code:

something general

```
typedef vector <Entitie*> container;
typedef vector <Entitie*>::iterator iter;
```

Inheritance structure

```
class SDLSpeedPowerUp: public CDS::SpeedPowerUp....
class SpeedPowerUp: public CDS::PowerUp....
class PowerUp: public CDS::Entitie....

class SDLHealthPowerUp: public CDS::HealthPowerUp....
class HealthPowerUp: public CDS::PowerUp....

class SDLEnemy: public CDS::Enemy....
class Enemy: public CDS::Vehicle....
```

sdlfactory.h (some code)

```
class SDLFactory: public CDS::AbstractFactory {
public:
SDLFactory();
virtual ~SDLFactory();
...
Enemy* createEnemy(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int);
...
HealthPowerUp* createHealthPowerUp(int,int,int);
SpeedPowerUp* createSpeedPowerUp(int,int,int);
...
};
```

sdlfactory.cpp (some code)

```
Enemy* SDLFactory::createEnemy(int x,int y,int maxHealth,int maxSpeed,int acceleration,int brakeSpeed,int damage,int bulletSpeed)
{
Waepon* loadedWaepon=createWaepon(x,y,damage,bulletSpeed);
return new SDLEnemy(x,y,maxHealth,maxSpeed,acceleration,brakeSpeed,loadedWaepon,this);
}
HealthPowerUp* SDLFactory::createHealthPowerUp(int x,int y,int effect){
return new SDLHealthPowerUp(x,y,effect,this);
}
SpeedPowerUp* SDLFactory::createSpeedPowerUp(int x,int y,int effect){
return new SDLSpeedPowerUp(x,y,effect,this);
}
```

gamelogic.h (some code)

```
class GameLogic 
{
protected:
AbstractFactory* factory;
public:
GameLogic(AbstractFactory*);
virtual ~GameLogic();

void createLevel(container&, int);
```

};

gamelogic.cpp (some code)

```
void GameLogic::createLevel(container& entities,const int level){
srand(time(NULL));
//create enemies
int x=0;
int spawnRate=1000-25*level;
while((x+=rand()%(spawnRate))<MAXHEIGHT){
    int y=rand()%MAXRIGHT;
    int maxHealth=rand()%(100+10*level);
    int speed=50+rand()%75;
    int acceleration=5+rand()%10;
    int brakeSpeed=10+rand()%15;
    int damage=25+rand()%(15*level);
    int waeponspeed=150+rand()%(150);
    entities.push_back(factory->createEnemy(x,y,maxHealth,speed,acceleration,brakeSpeed,damage,waeponspeed));
}
x=0;
while((x+=rand()%spawnRate)<MAXHEIGHT){
    int y=rand()%MAXRIGHT;
    int effect=50+rand()%50;
//the following line of code gives me a compile error
    entities.push_back(factory->createSpeedPowerUp(x,y,effect));
}

x=0;
while((x+=rand()%spawnRate)<MAXHEIGHT){
    int y=rand()%MAXRIGHT;
    int effect=50+rand()%50;
    entities.push_back(factory->createHealthPowerUp(x,y,effect));
}


}
```

compile error:

```
../GameLogic.cpp: In member function 'void CDS::GameLogic::createLevel(CDS::container&, int)':
../GameLogic.cpp:39: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<CDS::Entitie*, std::allocator<CDS::Entitie*> >::push_back(CDS::SpeedPowerUp*)'
/usr/include/c++/4.0.0/bits/stl_vector.h:602: note: candidates are: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = CDS::Entitie*, _Alloc = std::allocator<CDS::Entitie*>]
make: *** [GameLogic.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Does SpeedPowerUp derive from Entitie?

Comment: Yes it does. I added the inheritance structure to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add a `SpeedPowerUp` to a vector of `Entitie`. You probably want to make sure your `SpeedPowerUp` actually inherits from `Entitie`.

Comment: I followed up on my code, and speedpowerup inherits from powerup, which inherits from entitie. e.g. this code compiles (can't make a speedpowerup, because it contains a pure virtual function):

 SDLSpeedPowerUp* test=new SDLSpeedPowerUp(0,0,0,factory);
 entities.push_back(test);

Comment: @CrazyNilus: You should add those bits of the hierarchy to the question as it is more interesting than other pieces of logic for the particular error. Also, while you might be completely sure that the inheritance relationship exists, the compiler does not believe it. Is inheritance public?

Comment: Al the inheritance is defined public. I will add the inheritance structure in the post.

Comment: That was my conclusion as well... to bad its not the answer.  Since SpeedPowerUp and HealthPowerUp are identical you may want to just use HealthPowerUp generically as PowerUp.  If they have different time or benefit values you can use your factory to assign those as appropriate.  Another approach would be to make the PowerUp class a generic aka Template... you will still have to use the factory to assign it correctly in this case.
If you definitely need or want them separate though you are probably just going to have to debug the bejesus out of it.

Comment: As usual it was a trivial error. I forgot to include SpeedPowerUp.h and HealthPowerUp.h. Why it worked with HealthPowerUp I don't know, but I do now that now it works.